# is it possible in laravel to autoincrement primary key with string

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need a `primary key` with auto increment with string such as A1, A2, A3

if it's possible then please help me.

Comment: runtime you can append the Auto Increment ID and save...

Comment: yes but for this i need to fetch most recent id from database right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct way in Mysql but what you can do is create a table for storing the series, you can create a series table with columns 
ID, series, prefix and category
and you can fetch the next series number from the series table

Eg. 
Series table has following record

```
1 | 853 | CNO | customers
```

in above record ID is 1, 853 is series number and CNO is the prefix and category is customers and what I want is next customer should have series number `CNO853` then simply write a function

```
public static function getNextSeriesFor($category)
{
    $number = false;
    $details = \App\Series::where('category', $category)->first();
    if ($details != null) {
        $series_number = $details->series_number;
        $details->series_number = $details->series_number + 1;
        $details->save();
        $number = $details->prefix.$series_number;
    }

    return $number;
}
```

which will return me next series for Customers

Eg.
CNO853, CNO854, CNO855,...